# odd film on my cider

Tags: cider, yeast

I went to rack my cider into a secondary, pulled off the lid of my primary and saw this whitish film. I racked it and the film  stuck to the sides of the primary as the cider level dropped off. 
[cider film http://freesand.com/foto/thumbinator2.php?h=600&image=./fun/cider/2010/what-2.jpg](http://freesand.com/foto/thumbinator2.php?h=600&image=./fun/cider/2010/what-2.jpg)
Anyone know what that is? The cider didn't smell or taste off, I'm assuming that this was caused by yeast somehow? perhaps a wild yeast that didn't get killed off by my campden addition prior to pitching?

SG was 1.060 gravity when I racked was 1.000 so it's pretty much if not completely done fermenting.

The bulbous spots are air bubbles stuck under the film. The dark spots are allspice (or other mulling spices) floating at the surface just under the film.

Answer (score 1):

I had a film like that develop on an Octoberfest last year.  I only got worse with time and the flavor wasn't so good. It looks like a contamination to me.  I think its some sort of mold.
But if it tastes good to you then just keep going.

Comment: how did it get worse? was it turning sour? I've read that Brettanomyces can cause a film like this

Comment: The taste was musty and getting mustier.  Paper-like tasting and slick on the palate.